# Google Map Api v2 without map view

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc) and I taked this [image: result] ... without any error in Logcat view,If you have any idea about this error.

Thanks

I post to you my manifest code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.maps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Add Api key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAmklok-bwsgXzYLyBl4jLxFY3Gs6198YA" />
    </application>

    <!-- add Permisson -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- autres configs -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

</manifest>
```

All steps in many tutorials have a same code , I Think a problem is in emulator .

Comment: have you enabled maps for android in the google api console. Also cross check your api key . Also i suggest you test it on a real device if your testing it on emulator

Comment: This problem is usually derived from a problem in referencing `google-play-service` library.
Take a look at this blog post I wrote on how to integrate Google Maps in your application, especially the first 3 steps: [Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435) another cause of this could be that you haven't configured the Google API Console properly, so I suggest you to take a look at this guide as well: [Google Maps API V2 Key](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403) another reason that may cause this is if you have some kind of problem in your permissions in the manifest

Comment: yes , I take my api key from google console , but I have not idea to test my key ....

Comment: follow the steps suggested by Emil Adz. Did you refer google play services library in your android project?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes I refered to google play service library like it explained in Emil Adz but a same result !

Comment: @Phenix_dz can you post the code xml and manifest file

Comment: @Raghunandan that's my manifest code :

Comment: @Phenix_dz where have you posted? Post your layout xml code and the manifest file.

Comment: @Raghunandan that's my manifest code :

Comment: @Raghunandan I was updating my question ... , with manifest code .

Comment: Check also the warnings in Logcat, not only the errors. There's a warning message like "Could not connect to Google servers" (or something similar) when your app is misconfigured

Comment: @DhaneshBudhrani that's what i have like message : `Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above and eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, OpenGL ES 2.0 is supported from API 8. What is the API level of the emulator? Anyway, have you tested it on a physical device?

Comment: @DhaneshBudhrani I use emulator with Android Api 17 , I 'm confused !

Answer (score 0):

Google Map Api v2 wont show the map if you try to run it in Emulator or Device.
In order to show Map you need to sign the Application and then through command prompt try to install your application. Hope you will be able to get Map.

Few Steps required:-
1) You need add Libray project to your application

adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

From the tutorial i read from this http://agusharyanto.net/wordpress/?p=893 from indonesia, you must use the google service library on the Google API that you choose and use another application venton.apk and gms.apk from adb command. If you dont understand the languages, try understand by look at the image explanation.